# Size in the constructor initialization

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Stack
{
    int size;
    Stack(int size1)
    {
        size=size1;
    //  System.out.println("Constructor created"+size);//prints 3
    }
    int top1=-1;
    {System.out.println(size);}//prints 0
    int top2=size;
    {System.out.println(size);}//prints 0
    int []stack=new int[size];
}
```

Why is the size 0 in this case?

Comment: where do you initialize the Stack class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the order of initialization for those statements after main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154736/in-java-what-is-the-order-of-initialization-for-those-statements-after-main-met)

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 System.out.println printing 0 are called in instance initializers. These initializers are called **before** your contructor is called.

You can learn more here: [Static initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java)

Your full output must be

```
0
0
Constructor created3
```

Answer (score 0):

instance initializers are executed before constructors.. in your case, you are giving size value in constructor and before that it was zero..

[reference](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/10/java-class-instance-initializers/)