# java super class and sub class result

Tags: java

I have following  java code.

```
class A{
    static {
        System.out.print("1 ");
    }
    A(){
        System.out.print("3 ");
    }
    {
        System.out.print("2 ");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    static {
        System.out.print("4 ");
    }
    B(){
        System.out.print("6 ");
    }
    {
        System.out.print("5 ");
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new B();
    }
}
```

the result is above as following
`1 4 2 3 5 6`

this is include super class and sub class but I could not understand how is the result generating?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154736/in-java-what-is-the-order-of-initialization-for-those-statements-after-main-met

Comment: @Polygnome thats the same link in Nikolas' comment above

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari The comments gets added automatically if you VTC, as I did.

Comment: @Polygnome wasn't aware of that functionality, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way. You can't make an instance of the class until the class itself is initialized. The main method lies within Demo class with (Object -> Demo) which initializes those classes statically in that order. We are not creating an instance of demo since main is a static method, hence instance initialization blocks are not run for either at this time. Nothing is printed so it is less interesting here. *Classes are initialized upon first access of the class*

The next step is to identify that immediately in the main method we are requesting to create a B object. Hence we have to look at the B class dependency here is (Object -> A -> B). The static initialization blocks for Object would have been already run (if any) so we are left with A, then B.

After A Static Initialization Blocks

> 1

After B Static Initialization Blocks

> 1 4

Now since the request from *new B();* is for an instance of B, we have to go through each of the parent-most class (Object -> A -> B) and run their instance initialization blocks in order, followed by any relevant Constructor methods code. Unlike with the static initialization blocks above, this will be done *EACH* time an instance is constructed. This is done on a class-by-class basis. This example is a simpler case where there is only one constructor per class. Note that initialization blocks precede constructors. Nothing prints from Object class so we can disregard that.

After A instance initialization Blocks:

> 1 4 2

After A constructor (pertinent to our request)

> 1 4 2 3

After B instance Initialization Blocks

> 1 4 2 3 5

After B Constructor (pertinent)

> 1 4 2 3 5 6

Comment: got it as well Thanks!!!